# How can I parse a time duration string into time or duration object in Go?

Tags: parsing, go, time

How can I parse a string like the following "time elapsed: 00:00:02" into a go duration object or get hours/mintues/seconds from it?

Thanks!

Comment: https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Parse

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Sscanf` to parse the string, and then convert the result to duration:

```
var h,m,s int
fmt.Sscanf("time elapsed: 00:00:02","time elapsed: %d:%d:%d",&h,&m,&s)
dur:=time.Duration(h)*time.Hour+time.Duration(m)*time.Minute+time.Duration(s)*time.Second
```

Comment: time.Parse is flexible enough to account for fixed prefixes

Comment: @oakad, OP needs Duration, not Time though.